# Changing the text color of individual elements in a dynamically bound list

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, data-binding

Currently working on a little Windows Phone (7.5) application and one of the pages contains a ListBox that is bound to a list of elements.

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Listing}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}" />
```

The DataTemplate looks like the following where "Name" and "Description" are properties of the class "Entity":

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WordTemplate">
    <ListBoxItem Tap="WordTapped">                              
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Width="Auto" 
                     Text="{Binding Name}" 
                     FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"  
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                     TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     Margin="12, 0, 12, 0" />
            <TextBlock Width="Auto" 
                     Text="{Binding Description}" 
                     Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap"                                         
                     Margin="12, 0, 12, 12" />              
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

Is it possible - depending on the actual value of Name/Description - to change the font color of each TextBlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use a `ValueConverter` that converts your Name and Description to a brush:

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Converters:TextToBrushConverter x:Key="yourConverter"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    ...
    <TextBlock Width="Auto" 
          Text="{Binding Name}" 
          ...
          Foreground={Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource yourConverter}} />
```

The converter:

```
public class TextToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((string)value == "XXX")
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }

        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Working as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a property in your class that's a Brush generated based on your Name/Description tags, and bind it to the Foreground property of your text blocks, that should work...

Or, if you want to be slightly more canny, and not add properties to your Entity class, you could use a ValueConverter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx), let me know if you want some code that does it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create your own Binding Converter and use it in binding to Foreground.