# What is best way to customize binded text in WPF

Tags: wpf, controls

As the title says, I need to customize part of text in WPF, for example, I have a phrase "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", I need to bold the word "brown", or change background/foreground color of "fox". As far as I know, none of the regular WPF controls support that functionality, is there any open source/free alternatives?

P.S. the control should be bindable

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Run` to decorate your text.

```
    <TextBlock>
        <Run>The quick </Run>
        <Run FontWeight="Bold" Background="Yellow">brown</Run>
        <Run Foreground="Red"> fox </Run>
        <Run>jumps over the lazy dog.</Run>
    </TextBlock>
```

**Output**:

[image]

Also if you are using WPF 4.0 and later, **Microsoft have made `Text` property of Run as a Dependency Property instead of normal CLR property**. So, you can bind with it as well.

Refer [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2009/11/04/new-wpf-features-bindable-run.aspx) for Bindable Run.

Comment: Hmm, can I bind textblock to array of strings (words?) to generate as many Run as needed?

Comment: `Run` gets added as `Inlines` to the TextBlock i.e. you can do like this `textBox.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text ="Brown" });`. But `Inlines` is not a DP so you can't bind with it. However, you can use converter and pass string array binding in there along with textBox and there you can add inlines to textBlock. But there is no inbuilt support in TextBlock. Or Either have to subclass TextBlock say `MyTextBlock` and expose DP from it and can put the code of adding inlines in DP change.

Comment: Thanks, your answer led me to the solution. I just split the text in 3 parts in VM and bind it to 3 Runs. Not a clean solution but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I depends greatly on what you want to accomplish but you could use a RichTextBox of the WPF Toolkit as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4189726/752842).

Or you could add the binding capability to the .Net RichTextBox as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/343888/752842).

However, if you don't require anything so complex as a RichTextBox. You could use a ValueConverter and change the text you are going to show to something that better fits your needs.
Like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113991/changing-the-text-color-of-individual-elements-in-a-dynamically-bound-list).

Also depending a lot on what you need, you could create a User Control, with a Dependency Property "Text", and on the PropertyChanged, you break the text apart in smaller pieces, and bind them in different "sub properties" that will be shown in different TextBlocks (with different Styles) inside your User Control.

**Update** (added the suggestion from my comment)

If RichTextBox is not a solution, and the UserControl either, you could use a ValueConverter to accomplish this with the TextBlock.Inline, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058814/format-part-of-the-text-of-textblock-using-ivalueconverter/14059457#14059457).

Comment: RichTextBox has problems with unicode characters. It displays ? <-- symbols instead of unicode char. This happens only when data is acquired from binding though. Other than that, RichTextBox would be a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `HTML` to customize the text.. You can get a set of HTML codes [here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_ascii.asp)...

Comment: Do you know any control which supports html..?

Comment: TextBlock doesn't support HTML markup... You confuse TextBlock in another control..?

Comment: `&quot;` this is a HTML code right.. It will works for `TextBlock`